# flutter build error on chewie_player and localizations

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

I already using flutter clean but it doesn’t work

../../Resource/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.12.0/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:85:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'. resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Resource/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. const Scaffold({
^^^^^^^^
../../Resource/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.1.1/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:99:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Resource/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'. context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieAudioControllerProvider) as _ChewieAudioControllerProvider; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Resource/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:52:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'. context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null, ^^^^^^
../../Resource/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sry after i update to flutter 2.0.1, i forget to flutter pub upgrade